# Weka java: make arff file

Tags: java, weka, apriori

I created an ARFF file in java, but I would exclude the last two attributes (TAG, idSentence) from the calculation that will make a priori

```
 @attribute POS_node4_path12_72 {CC,CD,DT,EX,FW,IN,JJ,JJR,JJS,LS,MD,NN,NNS,NNP,NNPS,PDT,POS,PRP,PRP$,RB,RBR,RBS,RP,SYM,TO,UH,VB,VBD,VBG,VBN,VBP,VBZ,WDT,WP,WP$,WRB,#,$,.,',',:,(,),'\"','\'',“,”,‘,’}
 @attribute NER_node4_path12_72 {O,LOCATION,PERSON,ORGANIZATION,MISC,DATE,PERCENT,MONEY,NUMBER,TIME,ORDINAL}
 @attribute isTV_node4_path12_72 {true,false}
 @attribute rel_node4_path12_72 {agent,aux,auxpass,cop,csubj,csubjpass,dobj,iobj,nsubj,nsubjpass,pobj,xsubj}
 @attribute TAG {title,p,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6}
 @attribute idSentence {s000000003,s000000047,s000000057,s000000087,s000000112,s000000173,s000000178,s000000185,s000000187,s000000189,s000000203,s000000206,s000000214,s000000219,s000000299,s000000342,s000000350,s000000359,s000000366,s000000380,s000000381,s000000394,s000000413,s000000448,s000000458,s000000478,s000000479,s000000537,s000000540,s000000922,s000000953,s000001035,s000001041,s000001050,s000001064,s000001069,s000001091,s000001183,s000001196,s000001197,s000001202,s000001213,s000001215,s000001221,s000001237,s000001338,s000001492,s000001504,s000001511,s000001524,s000001528,s000001537,s000001602,s000001603,s000001622,s000001647,s000001661,s000001665,s000001768,s000001834,s000001853,s000001859,s000001875,s000001876,s000001901,s000001908,s000001973,s000002049,s000002052,s000002101,s000002103,s000002117,s000002313,s000002389,s000002391,s000002408,s000002476,s000002620,s000002641,s000002651,s000002653,s000002665,s000002670,s000002677,s000002683,s000002684,s000002733,s000002736,s000002744,s000002748,s000002758,s000002764,s000002905,s000002907,s000002910,s000002913,s000002917,s000002930,s000002932,s000002939,s000003016,s000003018,s000003153,s000003165,s000003269,s000003321,s000003334,s000003335,s000003401,s000003416,s000003430,s000003438,s000003463,s000003503,s000003565,s000003566,s000003567,s000003568,s000003572,s000003575,s000003578,s000003579,s000003580,s000003581,s000003582,s000003584,s000003585,s000003589,s000003590,s000003595,s000003603,s000003650,s000003673,s000003683,s000003692,s000003773,s000003817,s000003818,s000003864,s000003952,s000003959,s000003960,s000003978,s000004091,s000004134,s000004382,s000004384,s000004397,s000004497,s000004514,s000004518,s000004524,s000004531,s000004605,s000004613,s000004620,s000004622,s000004635,s000004662,s000004663,s000004676,s000004731,s000004750,s000004759,s000004879,s000004882,s000004886,s000004888,s000004890,s000004907,s000004915,s000005092,s000005108,s000005113,s000005130,s000005148,s000005162,s000005163,s000005198,s000005227,s000005248,s000005260,s000005264,s000005399,s000005411,s000005440,s000005452,s000005551,s000005554,s000005558,s000005582,s000005606,s000005797,s000005976,s000005993,s000006170,s000006391,s000006458,s000006462,s000006468,s000006475,s000006484,s000006572,s000006629,s000006701,s000007120,s000007253,s000007280,s000007292,s000007310,s000007396,s000007397,s000007468,s000007558,s000007642,s000007647,s000007816,s000007890,s000007926,s000007951,s000007956,s000007967,s000007970,s000007972,s000007973,s000007976,s000008221,s000008270,s000008307,s000008510,s000008729,s000008755,s000008763,s000008764,s000009041,s000009062,s000009302,s000009303,s000009305,s000009331,s000009332,s000009338,s000009339,s000009344,s000009355,s000009363,s000009367,s000009478,s000009792,s000010251,s000010469,s000010479,s000010484,s000010503,s000010523,s000010525,s000010532,s000010541,s000010880,s000011578,s000011810,s000011831,s000011907,s000011915,s000011916,s000011917,s000011918,s000011920,s000011925,s000011927,s000011928,s000011935,s000011946,s000011976,s000011980,s000011982,s000012017,s000012019,s000012021,s000012023,s000012025,s000012027,s000012028,s000012065,s000012086,s000012458,s000012470,s000012493,s000012505,s000012706,s000012718,s000013669,s000013905,s000014370,s000014382,s000014451,s000014512,s000014578,s000014590,s000014655,s000015377,s000015449,s000015833,s000016581,s000016867,s000016880,s000016917,s000016929,s000017602,s000017770,s000018363,s000018420,s000018507,s000018909,s000018921,s000019058,s000019064,s000019076,s000019130,s000019142,s000019143,s000019280,s000019292,s000019367,s000019368,s000019384,s000019405,s000019415,s000019422,s000019427,s000019433,s000019462,s000019465,s000019475,s000019575,s000019603,s000019620,s000019672,s000019820,s000019881,s000020150,s000020160,s000020164,s000020165,s000020167,s000020192,s000020198,s000020208,s000020217,s000020223,s000020228,s000020233,s000020247,s000020264,s000020295,s000020300,s000020303,s000020387,s000020391,s000020761,s000020801,s000021144,s000021145,s000021146,s000021151,s000021163,s000021165,s000021202,s000021206,s000021219,s000022123,s000022141,s000022153,s000022496,s000022508,s000022542,s000022559,s000022596,s000022606,s000022641,s000022677,s000022705,s000022707,s000023245,s000023249,s000023386,s000023387,s000023388,s000023389,s000023398,s000023418,s000023655,s000023667,s000024035,s000024316,s000024320,s000024321,s000024325,s000024326,s000024334,s000024348,s000024356,s000024410,s000024818,s000024945,s000025035,s000025117,s000025217,s000025350,s000025362,s000025381,s000025413,s000025418,s000025421,s000025484,s000025900,s000025961,s000026097,s000026716,s000026819,s000026902,s000026914,s000027183,s000027762,s000027774,s000028415,s000028427,s000028658,s000028682,s000028868,s000028919,s000028961,s000028973,s000029020,s000029025,s000029051,s000029237,s000029432,s000029444,s000029505,s000029555,s000029591,s000029594,s000029633,s000029852,s000029858,s000029870,s000029876,s000029877,s000029882,s000029891,s000029904,s000029906,s000029917,s000029918,s000029920,s000029921,s000029957,s000029963,s000029998,s000030299,s000030305,s000030355,s000030364,s000030394,s000030417,s000030425,s000030427,s000030428,s000030435,s000030436,s000030615,s000030797,s000030958,s000030977,s000030979,s000030980,s000030989,s000030994,s000030995,s000031004,s000031006,s000031015,s000031022,s000031025,s000031032,s000031041,s000031043,s000031044,s000031051,s000031063,s000031065,s000031066,s000031074,s000031085,s000031364,s000032247,s000032250,s000032304,s000032305,s000032306,s000032307,s000032315,s000032426,s000032438,s000032472,s000032484,s000032489,s000032493,s000032561,s000032770,s000032793,s000032797,s000032802,s000032831,s000032834,s000032836,s000032860,s000032873,s000032897,s000032992,s000033004,s000033162,s000033174,s000033263,s000033275,s000033297,s000033308,s000033509,s000033528,s000033634,s000033819,s000033839,s000033851,s000034343,s000034355,s000034377,s000034389,s000034419,s000034431,s000034589,s000034805,s000034817,s000034872,s000034884,s000034891,s000034931,s000034943,s000035213,s000035325,s000035530,s000035542,s000035669,s000035670,s000035672,s000035784,s000035900,s000035921,s000035966,s000035978,s000035983,s000036524,s000036594,s000036598,s000036601,s000036607,s000036644,s000036649,s000036654,s000036824,s000036834,s000036842,s000036846,s000036849,s000036877,s000036981,s000036993,s000037381,s000037434,s000037436,s000037449,s000037475,s000037480,s000037487,s000037512,s000037526,s000037580,s000037761,s000037773,s000037850,s000038734,s000038738,s000038740,s000038741,s000038742,s000038753,s000038755,s000038756,s000038771,s000038775,s000038777,s000038781,s000038782,s000038786,s000038795,s000038797,s000038812,s000038818,s000038823,s000038838,s000038839,s000039046,s000039047,s000039056,s000039064,s000039089,s000039119,s000039125,s000039171,s000039174,s000039178,s000039184,s000039187,s000039467,s000039468,s000039492,s000039550,s000040253,s000040555,s000040557,s000040559,s000040580,s000041145,s000041291,s000042078,s000042090,s000042485,s000042497,s000042553,s000042554,s000042589,s000042601,s000042608,s000042609,s000042684,s000043498,s000043614,s000043635,s000043658,s000043896,s000043926,s000044003,s000044005,s000044010,s000044012,s000044076,s000044391,s000044625,s000045392,s000045404,s000045589,s000045593,s000045604,s000045605,s000045606,s000045610,s000045611,s000045616,s000045632,s000045639,s000045641,s000045644,s000045683,s000045712,s000045755,s000046021,s000046380,s000046436,s000046556,s000046568,s000046730,s000046732,s000046733,s000046739,s000046833,s000046835,s000046850,s000046852,s000046855,s000046856,s000046860,s000046861,s000046867,s000046869,s000046871,s000046964,s000046967,s000046973,s000047092,s000047093,s000047095,s000047139,s000047140,s000047146,s000047234,s000047235,s000047335,s000047347,s000047809,s000047934,s000048069,s000048180,s000048342,s000048354,s000048416,s000048494,s000048497,s000048536,s000048551,s000048576,s000048586,s000048591,s000048606,s000048621,s000048624,s000049124,s000049428,s000049440,s000049466,s000049475,s000049492,s000049839,s000049880,s000049953,s000049965,s000049969,s000049989,s000050010,s000050022,s000050394,s000050396,s000050403,s000050412,s000050415,s000051252,s000051261,s000051278,s000051279,s000051514,s000051515,s000051516,s000051520,s000051539,s000051579,s000051655,s000051661,s000051919,s000051931,s000051988,s000052049,s000052185,s000052233,s000052235,s000052257,s000052318,s000052330,s000052378,s000052381,s000052398,s000052424,s000052445,s000052452,s000052461,s000052464,s000052611,s000052615,s000052924,s000052949,s000053063,s000053064,s000053067,s000053076,s000053078,s000053092,s000053098,s000053118,s000053120,s000053129,s000053133,s000053137,s000053141,s000053144,s000053154,s000053174,s000053177,s000053203,s000053210,s000053211,s000053225,s000053228,s000053229,s000053236,s000053240,s000053252,s000053259,s000053260,s000053262,s000053271,s000053276,s000053278,s000053279,s000053283,s000053287,s000053288,s000053289,s000053300,s000053497,s000053507,s000053514,s000053515,s000053547,s000053549,s000053552,s000053563,s000053578,s000053901,s000054165,s000054265,s000054666,s000054678,s000054843,s000055673,s000055675,s000055724,s000055742,s000055752,s000055826,s000055889,s000055901,s000055954,s000055972,s000055979,s000056010,s000056512,s000056524,s000056987,s000056999,s000057456,s000057458,s000057514,s000057515,s000057564,s000057584,s000057600,s000057859,s000057871,s000058060,s000058072,s000058088,s000058100,s000058103,s000058107,s000058150,s000058162,s000058198,s000058210,s000058228,s000058240,s000058313,s000058344,s000058355,s000058648,s000058786,s000059424,s000059436,s000059473,s000059474,s000059478,s000059493,s000059514,s000059527,s000059534,s000059543,s000059566,s000059567,s000059568,s000059572,s000059573,s000060215,s000060293,s000060998,s000061000,s000061003,s000061066,s000061077,s000061082,s000061241,s000061247,s000061258,s000061268,s000061271,s000061275,s000061279,s000061289,s000061297,s000061306,s000061349,s000061391,s000061403,s000061518,s000061520,s000061523,s000061525,s000061533,s000061549,s000061551,s000061564,s000061567,s000061569,s000061574,s000061580,s000061603,s000061604,s000061622,s000061648,s000061689,s000061701,s000062073,s000062155,s000062173,s000062188,s000062433,s000062434,s000063171,s000063719,s000063863,s000063884,s000063888,s000063894,s000063950,s000064123,s000064135,s000064136,s000064209,s000064221,s000064326,s000064493,s000064523,s000064538,s000064559,s000064739,s000064746,s000064747,s000065013,s000065015,s000065036,s000065044,s000065473,s000065485,s000065572,s000065584,s000065717,s000065816,s000065828,s000066737,s000066861,s000066949,s000066971,s000066974,s000066990,s000067070,s000067071,s000067218,s000067230,s000067246,s000067254,s000067256,s000067284,s000067357,s000067467,s000067468,s000067472,s000067480,s000067481,s000067484,s000067486,s000067487,s000067488,s000067491,s000067510,s000067511,s000067538,s000067543,s000067545,s000067581,s000067597,s000067608,s000067631,s000067729,s000067741,s000068235,s000068259,s000068762,s000068764,s000068769,s000068774,s000068779,s000068824,s000068877,s000068899,s000069123,s000069135,s000069155,s000069167,s000069587,s000069946,s000070181,s000070182,s000070592,s000070593,s000070597,s000070606,s000070773,s000070774,s000070789,s000070811,s000070813,s000070839,s000070842,s000070854,s000071066,s000071068,s000071070,s000071071,s000071073,s000071087,s000071090,s000071092,s000071093,s000071098,s000071119,s000071122,s000071123,s000071135,s000071144,s000071145,s000071152,s000071157,s000071158,s000071160,s000071163,s000071198,s000071430,s000071446,s000071555,s000071629,s000071663,s000071675,s000071721,s000071798,s000071976,s000072179,s000072197,s000072198,s000072244,s000072245,s000072285,s000072297,s000072756,s000072768,s000072897,s000073714,s000073726,s000073843,s000073855,s000073899,s000073911,s000073915,s000073919,s000073956,s000073958,s000073962,s000073967,s000073972,s000073980,s000073986,s000073987,s000074008,s000074033,s000074038,s000074222,s000074243,s000074247,s000074254,s000074286,s000074292,s000074294,s000074304,s000074559,s000074571,s000074796,s000074805,s000074825,s000074830,s000074832,s000074909,s000074956,s000075171,s000075707,s000075710,s000075715,s000075719,s000075747,s000075782,s000075803,s000075813,s000075851,s000075863,s000075938,s000075959,s000075984,s000075996,s000076156,s000076161,s000076169,s000076171,s000076174,s000076185,s000076197,s000076217,s000076235,s000076256,s000076260,s000076261,s000076383,s000077167,s000077173,s000077174,s000077176,s000077177,s000077182,s000077183,s000077184,s000077189,s000077213,s000077239,s000077301,s000077318,s000077324,s000077359,s000077370,s000077574,s000077577,s000077589,s000077810,s000077816,s000077855,s000078336,s000078462,s000079327,s000079355,s000079357,s000079401,s000079417,s000079418,s000079460,s000079543,s000079555,s000079576,s000079588,s000079665,s000079667,s000079669,s000079673,s000079688,s000079698,s000079770,s000079794,s000079870,s000080305,s000080317,s000080534,s000080610,s000080611,s000080623,s000080632,s000080765,s000081224,s000081231,s000081242,s000081273,s000081275,s000081294,s000081296,s000081297,s000081300,s000081314,s000081325,s000081335,s000081350,s000081362,s000081367,s000081368,s000081390,s000081404,s000081406,s000081410,s000081412,s000081417,s000082060,s000082207,s000082209,s000082373,s000082377,s000082397,s000082400,s000082407,s000082446,s000082529,s000082538,s000082555,s000082556,s000083115,s000083136,s000083166,s000083171,s000083235,s000083245,s000083252,s000083253,s000083285,s000083287,s000083290,s000083301,s000083316,s000083729,s000083770,s000083782,s000083925,s000083926,s000083977,s000083998,s000084221,s000084223,s000084247,s000084248,s000084251,s000084256,s000084265,s000084268,s000084278,s000084288,s000084303,s000084322,s000084332,s000084374,s000084382,s000084432,s000084433,s000084436,s000084441,s000084450,s000084453,s000084463,s000084473,s000084488,s000084507,s000084517,s000084559,s000084567,s000084612,s000085112,s000085145,s000085146,s000085292,s000085298,s000085314,s000085318,s000085322,s000085327,s000085336,s000085339,s000085345,s000085348,s000085352,s000085853,s000085878,s000085885,s000085909,s000085921,s000086147,s000086254,s000086266,s000086272,s000086288,s000086379,s000086380,s000086632,s000086633,s000086761,s000087042,s000087054,s000087204,s000087216,s000087265,s000087277,s000087457,s000087469,s000087686,s000087701,s000087736,s000087737,s000087738,s000088061,s000088073,s000088262,s000088264,s000088275,s000088290,s000088339,s000088343,s000088354,s000088356,s000088422,s000088770,s000088782,s000088888,s000088957,s000089096,s000089108,s000089148,s000089343,s000089350,s000089353,s000089362,s000089397,s000089459,s000089471,s000089498,s000089510,s000090070,s000090267,s000090369,s000090413,s000090425,s000090428,s000090467,s000090479,s000090820,s000090832,s000090852,s000090864,s000091201,s000091213,s000091624,s000091636,s000091651,s000091655,s000091660,s000091669,s000091678,s000091679,s000091689,s000091693,s000091700,s000091705,s000091708,s000091719,s000091726,s000091752,s000091973,s000091974,s000091989,s000091997,s000092005,s000092022,s000092023,s000092024,s000092033,s000092034,s000092042,s000092043,s000092045,s000092049,s000092050,s000092057,s000092075,s000092079,s000092169,s000092246,s000092258,s000092377,s000092507,s000092736,s000092738,s000092741,s000092804,s000092815,s000092820,s000092856,s000092905,s000092929,s000093001,s000093517,s000093549,s000093550,s000093551,s000093557,s000093559,s000093560,s000093571,s000093572,s000093582,s000093611,s000093613,s000093926,s000093938,s000094209,s000094651,s000094687,s000094699,s000095042,s000095548,s000095560,s000096149,s000096443,s000096505,s000096526,s000096546,s000097147,s000097151,s000097187,s000097199,s000097272,s000097289,s000097303,s000097305,s000097307,s000097328,s000097334,s000097345,s000097361,s000097367,s000097382,s000097385,s000097389,s000097390,s000097394,s000097558,s000097567,s000097571,s000097804,s000097878,s000097932,s000097935,s000097958,s000098173,s000098380,s000098385,s000098398,s000098404,s000098418,s000098425,s000098460,s000098464,s000098466,s000098474,s000098485,s000098492,s000098510,s000098511,s000098514,s000099307,s000099408,s000099439,s000099514,s000099560,s000099598,s000099659,s000099669,s000099674,s000099847,s000099848,s000099998,s000100010,s000100250,s000100368,s000100934,s000100937,s000100981,s000100996,s000101002,s000101010,s000101011,s000101017,s000101019,s000101050,s000101062,s000101070,s000101077,s000101093,s000101106,s000101145,s000101202,s000101214,s000101218,s000101219,s000101303,s000101304,s000101312,s000101341,s000101342,s000101343,s000101347,s000101348,s000101377,s000101378,s000101422,s000101428,s000101479,s000101491,s000101595,s000101805,s000102084,s000102085,s000102444,s000102456,s000102495,s000102507,s000102601,s000102625,s000102678,s000102939,s000103340,s000103349,s000103369,s000103374,s000103376,s000103453,s000103500,s000103518,s000103528,s000103532,s000103533,s000103535,s000103560,s000103566,s000103585,s000103591,s000103596,s000103601,s000103615,s000103632,s000103668,s000103671,s000103739,s000103751,s000103784,s000103786,s000103792,s000103867,s000103870,s000103912,s000103937,s000103947,s000104007,s000104075,s000104084,s000104098,s000104148,s000105198,s000105209,s000105242,s000105254,s000105255,s000105271,s000105281,s000105316,s000105323,s000105513,s000105824,s000105836,s000105910,s000106233,s000106245,s000106304,s000106316,s000106435,s000106453,s000106455,s000106653,s000106665,s000106852,s000106935,s000106965,s000106988,s000106997,s000106998,s000107018,s000107031,s000107041,s000107079,s000107233,s000107234,s000107237,s000107246,s000107257,s000107261,s000107272,s000107274,s000107280,s000107284,s000107286,s000107292,s000107300,s000107304,s000107305,s000107313,s000107315,s000107321,s000107323,s000107332,s000107335,s000107347,s000107669,s000107681,s000107715,s000107718,s000107765,s000107769,s000107772,s000107779,s000107787,s000107790,s000107835,s000108129,s000108141,s000108527,s000108539,s000108913,s000108936,s000109072,s000109084,s000109528,s000109535,s000109582,s000109611,s000109613,s000109617,s000109619,s000109644,s000109657,s000109687,s000109690,s000109703,s000110005,s000110021,s000110224,s000110227,s000110230,s000110235,s000110595,s000110913,s000111650,s000111694,s000111706,s000111792,s000111979,s000112007,s000112019,s000112175,s000112267,s000112273,s000112285,s000112291,s000112292,s000112297,s000112306,s000112319,s000112321,s000112332,s000112333,s000112335,s000112336,s000112372,s000112378,s000112413,s000112516,s000112528,s000112535,s000112537,s000112573,s000113074,s000113202,s000113214,s000113242,s000113254,s000113477,s000113591,s000113848,s000113851,s000113852,s000113859,s000113861,s000113870,s000113873,s000113874,s000113876,s000114082,s000114095,s000114108,s000114124,s000114126,s000114151,s000114152,s000114154,s000114169,s000114590,s000114596,s000114601,s000114608,s000114615,s000114621,s000114627,s000114643,s000114965,s000114994,s000115045,s000115072,s000115095,s000115096,s000115159,s000115171,s000115369,s000116466,s000116504,s000116542,s000116553,s000116554,s000116555,s000116742,s000116743,s000116761,s000116771,s000116790,s000116797,s000116798,s000116804,s000116897,s000116904,s000116905,s000116906,s000116910,s000116922,s000116944,s000116953,s000116971,s000116974,s000117211,s000117379,s000117380,s000117381,s000117395,s000117646,s000117670,s000117671,s000117672,s000117693,s000118989,s000119001,s000119100,s000119112,s000119500,s000119620,s000119621,s000119631,s000119713,s000119851,s000119882,s000119945,s000120210,s000120222,s000120642,s000120649,s000120829,s000121113,s000121125,s000121202,s000121230,s000121273,s000122112,s000122115,s000122121,s000122129,s000122142,s000122204,s000122229,s000122559,s000122563,s000122565,s000122570,s000122573,s000122575,s000122576,s000122586,s000122588,s000122597,s000122599,s000122600,s000122602,s000122611,s000122615,s000122623,s000122625,s000122626,s000122629,s000122632,s000122636,s000122644,s000122646,s000122653,s000122658,s000122660,s000122663,s000122690,s000122909,s000123460,s000123472,s000123633,s000123640,s000123642,s000123647,s000123661,s000123664,s000123875,s000124030,s000124040,s000124043,s000124060,s000124075,s000124077,s000124095,s000124298,s000124310,s000124361,s000124410,s000124411,s000124497,s000124509,s000124706,s000124718,s000124721,s000124751,s000124935,s000124947,s000125175,s000125187,s000125234,s000125454,s000125466,s000125502,s000125507,s000125635,s000125637,s000125639,s000125641,s000125653,s000125669,s000125712,s000125724,s000126188,s000126200,s000126545,s000126791,s000126810,s000126827,s000126841,s000127017,s000127019,s000127028,s000127051,s000127543,s000127544,s000127547,s000127572,s000127573,s000127575,s000127592,s000127594,s000127598,s000127602,s000127604,s000127608,s000127609,s000127655,s000127657,s000127658,s000127659,s000127660,s000127661,s000127671,s000127672,s000127699,s000127926,s000127938,s000128305,s000128307,s000128338,s000128339,s000128350,s000128383,s000128393,s000128401,s000128406,s000128412,s000128414,s000128418,s000128433,s000128441,s000128444,s000128452,s000128454,s000128457,s000128460,s000128469,s000128530,s000128543,s000129333,s000129334,s000129672,s000129684,s000129777,s000129789,s000130159,s000130274,s000130277,s000130286,s000130293,s000130297,s000130298,s000130374,s000130493,s000130498,s000130623,s000130889,s000130925,s000130937,s000131069,s000131071,s000131088,s000131242,s000131302,s000131558,s000131575,s000131596,s000131755,s000131778,s000131967,s000131979,s000132035,s000132047,s000132252,s000132271,s000132387,s000132462,s000132486,s000132494,s000132500,s000132509,s000132540,s000132549,s000132653,s000132669,s000132704,s000132716,s000132891,s000132893,s000132904,s000132905,s000132920,s000132923,s000132925,s000133376,s000133388,s000133392,s000133658,s000134086,s000134128,s000134173,s000134386,s000134404,s000134428,s000134439,s000134451,s000134539,s000134554,s000135645,s000135657,s000136027,s000136039,s000136280,s000136292,s000136551,s000136552,s000136989,s000137026,s000137030,s000137097,s000137391,s000137395,s000137400,s000137409,s000137410,s000137412,s000137416,s000137421,s000137431,s000137432,s000137440,s000137443,s000137476,s000137483,s000137486,s000137489,s000137505,s000137516,s000137519,s000137520,s000137521,s000137523,s000137527,s000137529,s000137534,s000137538,s000137540,s000137542,s000137547,s000137550,s000137551,s000137554,s000137557,s000137561,s000137595,s000137632,s000138017,s000138039,s000138051,s000138301,s000138313,s000138315,s000138529,s000138647,s000138659,s000138671,s000139332,s000139515,s000139536,s000140095,s000140126,s000140394,s000140583,s000140595,s000140606,s000141145,s000141156,s000141167,s000141168,s000141176,s000141364,s000141481,s000141767,s000141807,s000141812,s000142060,s000142064,s000142065,s000142160,s000142257,s000142324,s000142327,s000142329,s000142582,s000142630,s000142833,s000142916,s000143557,s000143569,s000143764,s000143787,s000143827,s000143829,s000143837,s000143872,s000143906,s000143918,s000143944,s000144040,s000144165,s000144232,s000144234,s000144237,s000144300,s000144311,s000144316,s000144354,s000144528,s000144540,s000144683,s000144689,s000144691,s000144693,s000144696,s000144701,s000144710,s000144712,s000144713,s000144719,s000144723,s000144728,s000144743,s000144744,s000144751,s000144853,s000144854,s000144856,s000144860,s000144865,s000144867,s000144871,s000144877,s000144881,s000144884,s000144889,s000145029,s000145067,s000145079,s000145197,s000145209,s000145210,s000145267,s000145279,s000145392,s000145404,s000145479,s000145908,s000146105,s000146162,s000146174,s000146212,s000146213,s000146224,s000146227,s000146261,s000146265,s000146272,s000146275,s000146278,s000146293,s000146298,s000146307,s000146312,s000146322,s000146335,s000146669,s000146676,s000146687,s000146690,s000146691,s000146701,s000146702,s000146704,s000146709,s000146767,s000146774,s000146776,s000146781,s000146797,s000147330,s000147366,s000147415,s000147785,s000148692,s000148693,s000148839,s000148851,s000149280,s000149292,s000149383,s000149505,s000149532,s000149605,s000149729,s000149747,s000149759,s000149894,s000150090,s000150094,s000150095,s000151170,s000151174,s000151254,s000151267,s000151268,s000151613,s000151614,s000151618,s000151623,s000151782,s000151830,s000151955,s000151967,s000151969,s000151971,s000151980,s000151992,s000152020,s000152068,s000152082,s000152087,s000152116,s000152124,s000152455,s000152456,s000152487,s000152496,s000152499,s000153741,s000153843,s000154192,s000154201,s000154202,s000154207,s000154255,s000154276,s000154391,s000154399,s000154400,s000154402,s000154409,s000154411,s000154428,s000154449,s000154502,s000154526,s000154528,s000154546,s000154772,s000154779,s000154801,s000154803,s000154805,s000154807,s000155185,s000155269,s000155396,s000155423,s000155450,s000155452,s000156008,s000156111,s000156118,s000156121,s000156153,s000156283,s000156303,s000156326,s000156347,s000156355,s000156387,s000156388,s000156389,s000156390,s000156394,s000156395,s000156397,s000156408,s000156409,s000156410,s000156437,s000156442,s000156824,s000156840,s000156963,s000157049,s000157065,s000157162,s000157163,s000157193,s000157200,s000157220,s000157400,s000157612,s000157617,s000157672,s000157778,s000157812,s000157816,s000157818,s000157823,s000157950,s000157996,s000157998,s000157999,s000158003,s000158014,s000158032,s000158033,s000158037,s000158039,s000158046,s000158047,s000158056,s000158065,s000158066,s000158085,s000158097,s000158117,s000158119,s000158142,s000158149,s000158153,s000158156,s000158157,s000158346,s000158728,s000158777,s000158864,s000158876,s000158881,s000158896,s000158913,s000158971,s000159020,s000159329,s000159354,s000159624,s000159625,s000159656,s000159659,s000159663,s000159665,s000159757,s000159791,s000160308,s000160352,s000161308,s000161319,s000161376,s000161705,s000161855,s000161857,s000161858,s000161859,s000161861,s000161863,s000161870,s000161969,s000162001,s000162003,s000162004,s000162007,s000162008,s000162009,s000162013,s000162015,s000162017,s000162205,s000162382,s000162454,s000162826,s000162828,s000162837,s000162931,s000162958,s000162970,s000163294,s000163549,s000164181,s000164193,s000164906,s000165293,s000165297,s000165397,s000165480,s000165481,s000165486,s000165491,s000165492,s000165493,s000165495,s000165500,s000165505,s000165509,s000165510,s000165632,s000165905,s000165953,s000166054,s000166060,s000166097,s000166466,s000166838,s000166839,s000167035,s000167115,s000167172,s000167336,s000167446,s000167858,s000167998,s000168059,s000168906,s000168937,s000169011,s000169012,s000169049,s000169055,s000169057,s000169104,s000169107,s000169131,s000169136,s000169310,s000169669,s000169793,s000169829,s000169872,s000170055,s000170338,s000170363,s000170382,s000170383,s000170384,s000170386,s000170837,s000171197,s000171200,s000171208,s000171221,s000171229,s000171233,s000171256,s000171273,s000171275,s000171294,s000171295,s000171704,s000171842,s000171843,s000171844}
 @data
```

Is there any particular filter that allows me to exclude from the calculation of apriori attributes TAG and idSentence?

**EDIT**:
I set the filter weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove and I set the last two attributes, and soon after I performed apriori! I think that is correct!

Answer (score 0):

What you edited is actually what i would suggest.

Another solution would be to open the file in weka, remove the attributes and save it without the attributes in a new file.